# Turn off click activity behind DialogFragment?

Tags: android, dialogfragment

I can't cancel the click event of the buttons in the background when I open a dialog fragment. I'm trying to call the dialog fragment via a button in another fragment.

```
public class DialogPaymentSuccessFragment extends DialogFragment {
private View root_view;
class rootViewClick implements OnClickListener {
    rootViewClick () {
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        DialogPaymentSuccessFragment.this.dismiss();
    }
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle bundle) {
    this.root_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_payment_success, viewGroup, false);
    ((FloatingActionButton) this.root_view.findViewById(R.id.fab)).setOnClickListener(new rootViewClick());
    return this.root_view;
}

@NonNull
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle bundle) {
    bundle = super.onCreateDialog(bundle);
    bundle.requestWindowFeature(1);
    return bundle;
}

public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

}

Comment: This look like a De-compiled code ..

Comment: Are you facing this issue when your activity contains CollapsingToolbarLayout

Comment: set root item of `dialog` clickable false in xml. add `android:clickable="false"` in `dialog_payment_success.xml` root item

Comment: post your xml code for the dialog fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set cancel able false in your `onCreateDialog` method

like this

```
this.setCancelable(false)
```

Comment: so your dialog appear ? and then on back click it disappear ?

Comment: no it didn't, and I can still click the button on the background

Comment: so you should try to create a dialog in new way ! what type of dialog you want to create

Answer (score 0):

If you define rootLayout, you can disable all views in the layout.You can also apply activity before opening the dialogfragment.

```
public static void enableDisableView(View view, boolean enabled) {
        view.setEnabled(enabled);
        if ( view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)view;

            for ( int idx = 0 ; idx < group.getChildCount() ; idx++ ) {
                enableDisableView(group.getChildAt(idx), enabled);
            }
        }
    }
```